# Input types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I would like to ask question. I am biginner in Hakskell and I have some diffictulties with very simple program, which should tell me if divident % divider == 0.

I have this code:

```
f::Integer -> Integer -> Bool
f x y = if ((x `mod` y) == 0) then True
                              else False

main = do putStrLn "Set up dividend"
          x <- getLine
          putStrLn "Set Up divider"
          y <- getLine
          f read x::Int read y::Int
```

but when I want to run it, I've got an error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `m0 b0'
    Expected type: m0 a0 -> m0 b0 -> Int
      Actual type: m0 a0 -> m0 b0 -> m0 b0
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "Set up dividend"
    In the expression:
        do { putStrLn "Set up dividend";
             x <- getLine;
             putStrLn "Set Up divider";
             y <- getLine;
             .... } ::
          Int
```

and I have really no idea, what is wrong. I've also tried `f x y (not f read x::Int .....)` without any results. I must do something wrong. I know there are many topics about this problem, but nothing helped me. I am missing something.

Comment: I don't know, why I can't insert spaces in code. Sure I have aligned lines

Comment: See the [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You need to precede each line of code with 4 spaces and also add an empty line in front of each code block.

Comment: Or select the code and click the code button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f read x::Int read y::Int
```

This applies the function `f` to the arguments `read`, `x`, `read` and `y`. It's also saying that the result of `f read y` should be an `Int` and that result of the whole thing should be an `Int` as well. That's obviously not what you want. What you want is to apply `f` to the results of `read x` and `read y`, so you need parentheses around those.

Another problem is that `f` takes `Integer`s as arguments, but you're telling `read` to give you `Int`s. You can fix that by changing `Int` to `Integer` or you can remove the type annotations altogether as they can be inferred. You could also change the type of `f` to accept any type of `Integral`, so that it works with both `Int` and `Integer`.

Lastly the type of `main` needs to be `IO ()`, but your definition evaluates to a `Bool`. Maybe you want to print the `Bool`?

The combination of `getLine` and `read` can be simplified to `readLine` by the way.

So you could do:

```
main = do putStrLn "Set up dividend"
          x <- readLine
          putStrLn "Set Up divider"
          y <- readLine
          print $ f x y
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in your final line:

```
f read x::Int read y::Int
```

This code is basically saying `f read x read y`, which is of type `Int` and where `f read x` is also of type `Int`. You have to add parentheses so that `f` is applied properly and that the type annotations are used on the correct terms. You get:

```
f ((read x) :: Int) ((read y) :: Int)
-- or with fewer parentheses, but meaning the same thing:
f (read x :: Int) (read y :: Int)
```

Also the if-statement in your definition of `f` is unnecessary, why not use:

```
f x y = (x `mod` y) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

On a first glance you need to use  `f (read x::Int) (read y::Int)` because in your case you are passing functions to you f. I suggest you to take a look at [Learn you Haskell for gread good](http://learnyouahaskell.com), the [input/output chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) in detail. It is one of the best, newbie friendly ressources out there as far as I know.